# java, reflection , innerclass,

Tags: java, reflection, anonymous-inner-class

Hi i want to get the object of inner class using reflection but i am getting some error in it.

code is:-

```
package reflaction;
public class MyReflection {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException  {
    Class obj = Class.forName("reflaction.MyReflection$TestReflection");
    TestReflection a = (TestReflection) obj.newInstance();
    a.demo();
}

class TestReflection {

    public void demo(){
        System.out.println("reflection occurs");
    }
    }
}
```

and the error is :--

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InstantiationException: reflaction.MyReflection$TestReflection
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at reflaction.MyReflection.main(MyReflection.java:10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
public class MyReflection {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
        InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
        NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException,
        InvocationTargetException {
    Class outer = Class.forName("reflaction.MyReflection");
    Object outerInstance = outer.newInstance();

    Class<?> inner = Class
            .forName("reflaction.MyReflection$TestReflection");
    Constructor<?> constructor = inner.getDeclaredConstructor(outer);

    TestReflection innerInstance = (TestReflection) constructor
            .newInstance(outerInstance);

    innerInstance.demo();
}

class TestReflection {

    public void demo() {
        System.out.println("reflection occurs");
    }
}
```

Have a look at the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) of `getDeclaredConstructor(Class<?>... parameterTypes)`. It says:

> ... If this Class object represents an inner class declared in a non-static context, the formal parameter types include the explicit enclosing instance as the first parameter.

So, giving the enclosing instance as first parameter will create a new instance of the inner class:

```
    TestReflection innerInstance = (TestReflection) constructor
            .newInstance(outerInstance);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `TestReflection` is an inner class it can only exist within an instance of the outer class `TestReflection`. Thus you have to provide an instance of `TestReflection` when instantiating the inner class.

Use this:

```
public class MyReflection {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class<?> testReflectionClass = Class
                .forName("reflection.MyReflection$TestReflection");
        MyReflection myReflection = new MyReflection();
        Object newInstance = testReflectionClass.getDeclaredConstructor(
                MyReflection.class).newInstance(myReflection);
        TestReflection testReflection = (TestReflection) newInstance;
        testReflection.demo();
    }

    class TestReflection {

        public void demo() {
            System.out.println("reflection occurs");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the non-static inner class can only be instantiated using the outer class instance, like

```
Outer outer = new Outer();
Inner inner = outer.new Inner();
```

Secondly - as far as i know, java reflection api does not provide an ability to instantiate the non-static inner classes. It is possible only for static ones. So if you dont need the inner class to be dynamic and referenced with outer instance - just add a 'static' modifier for inner class and your code will work.

Comment: It provides it by adding a hidden argument to all non-static inner class constructors which takes an instance of the enclosing class.

Answer (score 0):

set `TestReflection` class `static`, like:

```
package reflaction;

public class MyReflection {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException  {

    Class<?> obj = Class.forName("reflaction.MyReflection$TestReflection");
    TestReflection a = (TestReflection) obj.newInstance();
    a.demo();
}

static class TestReflection {

    public void demo(){
        System.out.println("reflection occurs");
    }
}
}
```

The other way is to create `MyReflection` instance aka: `Class.forName("reflaction.MyReflection").newInstance();` and after from that instance load `"reflaction.MyReflection$TestReflection"`